# Which one Skype is normal (old), Skype for Desktop or just Skype?

Tags: windows-8, skype

Have problems running Skype. Tray icon is either gray or green but no context menu can be called. So I wonder, how to run old-fashion Skype (not one refactored by MS for Windows 8), what is it's name? I have two: "Skype" and "Skype for desktop".

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Skype?  Skype for Desktop is the traditional desktop Skype program.  It would be the same version you install on any other Windows operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skype for Desktop is to be used in your desktop environment, like the old one.

Skype is the application that you use in full screen via the metro interface.

Comment: You can also try snapping the metro Skype to the side of the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Skype Desktop is the old one, the other is for metro interface i guess. If you have problems with Skype go to your control panel and delete both, then visit the web page [HERE](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-windows/downloading/) and download Skype for Desktop again.